# Open new tab in my default browser and several links inside my site automatically

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm using the following code to open site in internet explorer

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
  Arguments = "http://www.cnn.com",
  FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe",
  RedirectStandardInput = true,
  UseShellExecute = false
};

System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

after the web page start i want every few seconds to open (automatically) links inside the web page without to define before the URLs (like web crawler), it's possible to do it ?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to open these links? What end goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to build web crawler who surf into several links inside URL

Comment: Then why do you need a Web browser?

Comment: cause i want to practice on C#, it is possible to do it ?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but it's **totally not scalable** as [you seem to have found out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750408/how-to-open-new-url-on-the-same-open-tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, because you open the browser in different process of your program and it already out of your control. It could be possible if you use [WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx) in your program, read document and find the URLs with something like regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

This may end up a monster! You could use easily use System.Net to download you starting page, pull out any links and then pass them back through recursively and at each hit call an instance of the browser using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start. That way you are crawling using your app and just sending each page to the browser independantly.

Not sure this is advisable though as it will soon eat your resources - sounds like a virus from yester-year to me.