# How to open new url on the same open tab?

Tags: c#, web-crawler

i am use this code in order to open all link from specific URL, each link will open with new tab, this cause a huge memory use, how can i open the new link on the existing Tab ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = null;
    string googleChoromePath = "C:\\Users\\Dandin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
    string argument = "";
    string url = "http://edition.cnn.com/";
    WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
    string st = wClient.DownloadString(url);
    List<string> list = LinkFinder.Find(st);
    processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(googleChoromePath);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        argument = list[i];

        try
        {
            if (argument.StartsWith("http://"))
            {
                processStartInfo.Arguments = argument;
                processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

                Process googleChrome = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why are you opening so many URLs in the browser? And what would be the point of opening some URL and then immediately opening some other URL?

Comment: i want to build web crawler, continue to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748075/open-new-tab-in-my-default-browser-and-several-links-inside-my-site-automaticall and the low time of sleep its only for testing

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense. Web crawler would download the pages and process them, not open them in a browser. Why do you want to open the pages in the browser?

Comment: But, why? Are you doing load testing of your website?